# Pointer to Class AND pointer to method

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

how can I make double pointer to class and member function?

Basically, I have some (quite a few) generic classes accepting function pointers like this:

```
void Gen::regCallback(void (*callback)(void const *), void const * callbackData)
```

and in classes, I often have either functions like this

```
void Foo::doSomething(void const * instance) // this one is static
{
    auto myself((Foo const *)instance);
    myself->...do stuff...
    myself->...do stuff...
    myself->...do stuff...
}
```

or method/function twins

```
void Foo::doSomething(void const * instance) // this one is static
{
    ((Foo const *)instance)->doSomething();
}
void Foo::doSomething() const
{
    ...do stuff...
    ...do stuff...
    ...do stuff...
}
```

I would like to somehow reduce clutter in the code (by registering directly members),
I am aware of option:

```
void Gen::regCallback(void (Foo::*callback)(void const *), Foo const * member);
```

but I need to make also class type (Foo) to be passed as parameter (i.e. Foo1, Foo2, FooTotallyDifferent)

For various reasons I cannot use template for class type, so

```
template <typedef T>
class Gen
{
    void regCallback(void (T::*callback)(void const *), T const * member)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

is no option for me

Comment: have you considered use `std::function` and lambda functions? they ease the whole callback thing..

Comment: @DavidHaim Hmm... I was not aware of std::function, seems plausible, going to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want is to be able to register *any* callable that takes zero arguments and returns void. Since presumably you will be storing these callbacks somewhere, you also will need type erasure - since you want to be able to call `Foo::doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` and even `Bar::someMethod(with, some, args)` agnostically. For all of that, and more, there's [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Specifically in your case, `std::function<void()>`.

Usage is simple. A `std::function<void()>` can be constructed from any function that matches that signature. Here is an example that adds several different callable types to a vector of one `std::function` type:

```
using Callback = std::function<void()>;
std::vector<Callback> callbacks;

void free() { std::cout << "free\n"; }
void free(int arg) { std::cout << "free " << arg << "\n"; }
struct Foo {
    void something() const { std::cout << "Foo with " << i << "\n"; }

    int i;
};

callbacks.emplace_back(free); // normal function pointer

Foo f;
callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::something, f)); // member function bound to instance, copies f

callbacks.emplace_back([]{ free(42); }); // lambda calling function with specific argument

f.i = 64;
callbacks.emplace_back([&]{ f.something(); }); // captures f
f.i = 72;

// call all of them
for (auto fn : callbacks) {
    fn();
}
```

That will print

```
free
Foo with 42
free 42
Foo with 72
```

Comment: I mark this as answer,
I just don't get:
    callbacks.emplace_back(std::bind(&Foo::something, i));
where did "i" come from

Comment: i is a member variable of foo

Comment: @chmirko Typo, was supposed to be `f`.